# POI can't add pciture to an xls template containing charts

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

**Context** : I'm using POI to generate xls report for automated tests execution

**Requirements** : I'm having a template with, as first sheet, a Synthesis for all execution, this sheet is containing some chart (Line charts)

**ToDo** : I want to add some weather picture (jenkins style)

**Main problem** : My code fail (compile and execute ok but xls can't be opened) when their is some charts in the sheet

**Debug** : I deleted charts and it works fine

**Here is my code snippet (just for adding picture)**
H

```
SSFSheet SyntheseSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
String weatherFolder = parentPath+"/reports/templates/logoMeteo/";
InputStream pictureStream = new FileInputStream(weatherFolder+"1.png");
byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(pictureStream);
int pictureIdx = workbook.addPicture(bytes, Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG);
pictureStream.close();
CreationHelper helper = workbook.getCreationHelper(); 
Drawing drawing = SyntheseSheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
ClientAnchor anchor = helper.createClientAnchor();
anchor.setCol1(1); 
anchor.setRow1(17);
anchor.setCol2(3); 
anchor.setRow2(22);
Picture pict = drawing.createPicture(anchor, pictureIdx);
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(OutputFilePath);
workbook.write(fileOut);
fileOut.close();
```

I'm coding in java (maven).
I'm using Apache POI **3.15**

Please help, thanks

Comment: which "error" occurs if you want to open the file?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer That the file is corrumpted, then Excel close (a problem happened ...)

Comment: have you tried with closing the workbook before closing the FOS?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I'll try it now and give you feedbacks.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer : nope still same error ...

Comment: I think there is a problem with the "existence" of charts in the same sheet

Comment: have a look here. https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/limitations.html this might answer it

Answer (score -1):

```
   Try to do it with this method

   final FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(imagePath);
   final CreationHelper helper = workbook.getCreationHelper();
   final Drawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();

   final ClientAnchor anchor = helper.createClientAnchor();
   anchor.setAnchorType( ClientAnchor.MOVE_AND_RESIZE );


   final int pictureIndex =workbook.addPicture(stream, Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG);


    anchor.setCol1(0);
    anchor.setRow1(LOGO_ROW); // same row is okay
    anchor.setRow2(LOGO_ROW );
    anchor.setCol2(1);
    final Picture pict = drawing.createPicture( anchor, pictureIndex );
    pict.resize();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the methode addPicture accept as first parameters byte[] type, can put a FileInputStream, any help ?